# How do I figure out the line of where a deprecation warning is occurring during my RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, deprecation-warning

I’m using RSpec-rails 4.1, Rails 6.1 and FactoryBot 6.2.  When running RSpec examples, I see messages like the below

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: This feature will be removed in the next major release.
```

There is no other information besides the above.  In my config/environments/test.rb file< I have this set

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
```

However, nowhere in my log/test.log file do I see a line with “DEPRECATION WARNING: This feature will be removed in the next major release” or anything resembling a stack trace of the warning.  If I change the above to

```
config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr
```

I still don’t see a stack trace.  How can I get more info about what precise line is causing the deprecation warning?

Comment: Do you know which test is triggering the warning?

Comment: No, I don't.  I figure if I can get a stack trace it would pinpoint the line taht's generating the warning.

Comment: Have you tried `config.active_support.deprecation = :raise`? Or running the spec files one by one?

Comment: Hi, Ah didn't know about ":raise".  That pinpoints where the warning is coming from.

Comment: This deprecation message might be caused by [attr_encrypted gem](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted/blob/master/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb#L127). 

It might be ignoring active support configuration if Ruby resolves `warn` to [`Kernel#warn`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_6_3/Kernel/warn) instead of [`ActiveSupport::Deprecation::Reporting#warn`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveSupport/Deprecation/Reporting/warn)